# Perl Mason strange behavior - compilation gets error at $m which is not there

Tags: perl, compilation, mason

I have this piece of code (shortened):

```
my $lins = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT id, name, popis, pic FROM line", { Slice => {} }) or die 'Query (SELECT from line) failed';
...
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, name, line_id, colorset_id FROM products WHERE id=?");
if ($prod_id =~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) {
        $sth->execute($prod_id);
        my $prod;
        while ($prod = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
                print "I have ".$prod->{id}." ". $prod->{name}." <br>";
</%perl>
...
<tr><td>Model row</td><td>
<select id="line_id" name="line_id">
% foreach my $lined (@$lins) {
% if ( $lined->{id} == $prod->{line_id} {
<option value="<% $lined->{id} %>" selected><% $lined->{name} %></option>
% } else {
<option value="<% $lined->{id} %>"><% $lined->{name} %></option>
% }
% }
</select>
...
```

There's problem with compilation:

```
error:      Error during compilation of /var/www/mason/eshop/prod.mas:
syntax error at /var/www/mason/eshop/prod.mas line 83, near "$m"
Execution of /var/www/mason/eshop/prod.mas aborted due to compilation errors.
context:    
...     
79:     <tr><td>Modelova rada</td><td>
80:     <select id="line_id" name="line_id">
81:     % foreach my $lined (@$lins) {
82:     % if ( $lined->{id} == $prod->{line_id} {
83:     <option value="<% $lined->{id} %>" selected><% $lined->{name} %></option>
84:     % } else {
85:     <option value="<% $lined->{id} %>"><% $lined->{name} %></option>
86:     % }
87:     % }
...
```

As you can see, there's nothing suspicious at the line 83. The same mechanics with another variable (colorset_id) works well.
Do you anybody know what's wrong with this? There's no ANY reference to $m as the compiler says.. I'm confused...

Comment: The error is not in line 83. Does any variable in your code start with "$m"? It's hard to help you: maybe, there is a syntax error in another place. Try to incrementally increase your code from the simplest working version by adding new blocks. Maybe, you will be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: I presume that Mason generates Perl code from that template? Is there a way of obtaining that Perl code from Mason?

Comment: I presume that Mason generates Perl code from that template? (yes) Is there a way of obtaining that Perl code from Mason? (I think it automatically saves it to disk)

Comment: That's the "strange" - I have not any $m... in the code, and I already renamed variables, that they are not $line etc (which *could* be some reserved worlds, but accd to mason docs, they are not, but better to use another ones).

Answer (score 1):

Aaaargh! there was syntax error at if condition - missing bracket ")"
Sorry for asking, I spent hours with this :-(